# Not getting pure color while using the FastLED with WS2812b

Tags: library, ws2812

I am working with the LED strip **WS2812b** and **FastLED** library, currently I have only 3 LEDs connected in such a way that the first 2 receive a color *(say green)* and the last one receives another one *(say blue)*.

The problem is that by putting the color *(blue)* on the last LED, the other two (currently only in *green*) also take a portion of *blue*, preventing it from being a pure (*green*) color. It happens with any combination of color.

I leave the piece of my code referring to the LED strip:

```c++
#include "FastLED.h"
#define NUM_LEDS 3
#define DATA_PIN 2

//Variables declaration...
....

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
.....

  }


void loop() {
  ReadMySerial();       //This function take data from serial port and set the color for the leds
  FastLED.setBrightness(brigth);

  for (int pinNo = 0; pinNo <= 2; pinNo++){
    leds[pinNo].setRGB(green_inactive,red_inactive,blue_inactive);
    FastLED.show();
      if (digitalRead(pinNo+3) == HIGH){
        leds[pinNo].setRGB(green_reactive,red_reactive,blue_reactive);
           FastLED.show();
            }
        }


  }
```

I already change the pin for where I put the signal for the LED strip, I try to change the type of LED strip

- `FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LEDS)`
- `FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, RGB>(leds, NUM_LEDS)`
- `FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS)`

without any success...

Can anyone point me in the rigth direction?

Edit: actually, the first LED of the strip is flashing, not in the way of the **Blinking** example, but I can see a little flashing.

Comment: Hey @gre_gor, how can I put lists when I'm asking?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

I can see what the problem is, I put `FastLED.show();` where it should not, that's also why I saw the flash ... fix it and here's the result:

```
void loop() {
  ReadMySerial();       //This function take data from serial port and set the color for the leds
  FastLED.setBrightness(brigth);

  for (int pinNo = 0; pinNo <= 2; pinNo++){
    leds[pinNo].setRGB(green_inactive,red_inactive,blue_inactive);
    FastLED.show();
    if (digitalRead(pinNo+3) == HIGH){
      leds[pinNo].setRGB(green_reactive,red_reactive,blue_reactive);
    }
  }

  FastLED.show(); //NOW IS IN THE RIGHT POSITION
}
```